# Output in Variable

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a new script for a backup solution. 
Now I want to get the error message, which I saw in terminal, to a log file. Therefor I want to write the output in a variable.

I wrote an error in it. The option "defaults-file" is missing a "--".

With a simple example it worked:

```
#!/bin/bash
log=$(date)
echo $log
```

This is the code snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=`date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S`.sql
log=$(`mysqldump defaults-file=/home/user/.my.cnf cloud > backup_$DATE`)

echo $log
```

Comment: Use backticks **or** `$( )`, not both. `$( )` is preferred, see [BashFAQ #82](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082). BTW, I don't think this is quite a duplicate, since if I'm reading it right, the goal is to capture stderr in a variable, *and* redirect stdout to a file.

Answer (score 2):

You are not capturing any string in `log` because your `mysql` command is sending all its standard output to a file.

Capturing standard output in a variable so that you can `echo` that variable to standard output is an antipattern anyway (and a [bug if you don't double-quote the string you `echo`)](/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable/27701642).

If you want to redirect the standard error output to standard output, use another redirection.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Also, don't use uppercase for private variables
# and prefer $(command) over obsolescent `command`
date=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).sql
mysqldump defaults-file=/home/user/.my.cnf cloud 2>&1 > "backup_$DATE"
```

The `2>&1` redirect causes error messages to go to the standard output file descriptor.  The `>` redirect causes the (original) standard output to go to a file.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Rolled back your edit. The intent is precisely to get stdout and stderr to two different places.